# C++, wxWidgets + vcpkg + Cmake = undefined reference to на весь wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, vcpkg

Пробую изучать C++, до этого с относительным успехом писал на Rust и там вполне вменяемый пакетный менеджер, который приятно и легко использовать. Здесь же определился, что, наверное, самым удобным для билда будет сочетание CMake + vcpkg (я так понимаю, пакетный менеджер для плюсов), так как устанавливать большинство зависимостей вручную кажется весьма требующим времени занятием. А что если придётся работать над проектом на другой машине? Ладно, ближе к делу.

Для начала решил создать простенькое GUI приложение, выбор пал на wxWidgets. Настроил проект CMake, установил VCPKG, с помощью него поставил wxwidgets:x64-windows. И вот, уже сконфигурировал проект для внедрения wxWidgets, VS Code уже сам автоматически дополняет названия классов/функций и т.д., думаю, что всё уже хорошо. Но стоит мне попытаться скомпилировать проект, и на абсолютно каждое определение wxWidgets, которое было задействовано, выдаёт ошибку undefined reference to... .

Вот небольшой кусок из ошибки при компиляции:

```
CMakeFiles\Learn.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `wxWeakRef<wxWindow>::OnObjectDestroy()':
D:/libs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/wx/weakref.h:89: undefined reference to `__imp_wxTheAssertHandler'
```

Вот конфигурация Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Learn VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(Learn main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows)
set(-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/libs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
include(D:/libs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS net core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_include_directories(Learn PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Learn PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

include(CPack)
```

Скопированный Hello World с туториала по wxWidgets

```
// wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();

private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event);
};
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    Close(true);
}
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

Comment: Видимо у вас конфликт: разные конфигурации сборки в части платформы (32 бит / 64 бит), или линковки статических / данамических вариантов библиотек, или т.п. Лучше сразу приноравливайтесь собирать все руками или делать свой пакетный менеджер. То, что наваливает CMake + vcpkg, имеет смысл использовать только в том случае, если у вас есть четкое понимание, что, как и на каком этапе будет использоваться.

Comment: У крестов нет стандартного пакетного менеджера. Vcpkg хорош в первую очередь с Visual Studio. Если у вас не студия а MinGW, то лучше заменить его на MSYS2 (и оттуда же ставить сам MinGW).